# activating a sub procedure when any cell is changed anywhere in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Could anyone please tell me how do I make my sub procedure run, if any cell in the workbook has it's value changed. I know it has something to do with the workbook.sheetchange event but I can't quite figure it out. Thanks in advance :).

Comment: [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640) will get you started

Answer (score 0):

In the `ThisWorkbook` code module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _
                                ByVal Target As Range)

    Debug.Print "Range " & Target.Address() & _
         " was changed on sheet '" & Sh.Name & "'"

End Sub
```